# Own service worker in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm new in `service workers` and just began to learn them. 
I already read, that when I'm using CRA with my own service worker, I need to `eject`.

My question now is, why I can't implement my own service worker in CRA by modifying these lines in `index.js` or do I miss something? Why is this not working. Maybe someone can give me an explanation. I'm sure, I forgot to think about some issue, but I want to understand, why this will not work. Thanks in advance.

I started to modify `index.js` this way:

`import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';`

to

`import registerMyServiceWorker from './registerMyServiceWorker';`

and called

`registerMyServiceWorker();`

instead of

`registerServiceWorker();` at the end.

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerMyServiceWorker from './registerMyServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerMyServiceWorker();
```

**registerMyServiceWorker:**

```
export default function registerMyServiceWorker() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
          // Registration was successful
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          // registration failed :(
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
}
```

**service-worker.js:**

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'service-worker-test-app-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/favicon.ico'
  '/static/js/bundle.js',
  'sockjs-node/info',
  'sockjs-node/718/yzsjlzx4/websocket'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache - public');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: This looks ok to me. Did you try in incognito? New service worker wont take effect until all tabs that depend on old one are closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, you're right. It works. I wondered because the Offline mode did not succeed, but I missed a file in the caching.

Comment: awesome! glad you got it working :)